# Running total by date/ID based on latest change to value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, cumulative-sum

I have a unique case where I want to calculate the running total of quantities day over day. I have been searching a lot but couldn't find the right answer. Code-wise, there is nothing much I can share as it refers to a lot of sensitive data

Below is the table of dummy data:

[image: Data]

As you can see, there are multiple duplicate IDs by date. I want to be able to calculate the running total of a date as follows:

**For 2022/03/24, the running total would be 9+33 = 42, on 2022/03/26 the running total should be 9+31 = 40. Essentially, the running total for any given day should pick the last value by ID if it changed or the value that exists. In this case on 2022/03/26 for that date, for ID 2072, we pick 31 and not 33 because that's the latest value available.**

Expected Output:

[image: Expected OP]

There maybe be many days spanning across and the running total needs to be day over day.

Possible related question: [SQL Server running total based on change of state of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646686/sql-server-running-total-based-on-change-of-state-of-a-column)

PS: *For context, ID is just a unique identifier for an inventory of items. Each item's quantity changes day by day. In this example, ID 1's inventoyr last changed on 2022/03/24 where as ID 2072's changed multiple times. Running total for 2022/03/24 would be quantities of inventory items on that day. On 26th there are no changes for ID 1 but ID 2072 changed, the inventory pool should reflect the total as current inventory size of ID 2072+ current size of ID 1. On 26th, again ID 1 did not have any change, but ID 2072 changed. Therefore inventory size = current size of ID 2072 + current size of ID 1, in this case, 40. Essentially, it is just a current size of inventory with day over day change.*

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please show the expected result in text and also your attempted query

Comment: Updated with expected OP. code-wise this is a dummy data I created.

Comment: What is your expected result if there are some different id in your table? still unclear from your sample data and expect result

Comment: Expected result remains the same as shown above by dates. But running total needs to calculate the latest value for a given date by the latest value against the ID. In the above example as explained, For 2022/03/24, the running total would be 9+33 = 42, on 2022/03/26 the running total should be 9+31 = 40. Essentially, the running total for any given day should pick the last value by ID if it changed or the value that exists. In this case on 2022/03/26 for that date, for ID 2072, we pick 31 and not 33 because that's the latest value available. The final result need not consider the above IDs

Comment: @AmalSailendran I had write an answer you can try it

Comment: Is ID =1 seed/baseline for each calculation? The problem is still not clear. Can your provide a more clear example?

Comment: ID is just a unique identifier for an inventory of items. Each item's quantity changes day by day. In this example, ID 1's inventoyr last changed on 2022/03/24 where as ID 2072's changed multiple times. Running total for 2022/03/24 would be quantities of inventory items on that day.  On 26th there are no changes for ID 1 but ID 2072 changed, the inventory pool should reflect the total as current inventory size of ID 2072+ current size of ID 1. Essentially, it is just a current size of inventory with day over day change. Hope this helps

Comment: Sample data and expected results *as text* would help immensely

Comment: `nothing much I can share as it refers to a lot of sensitive data` The dummy data you posted is fine, just meaningless numbers and dates.  Surely you can put together a small *text* example using those values? Then hopefully someone could suggest a better option than a cursor .... Cursors should be avoided whenever possible, because they work row-by-row, and are usually the *least efficient* way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a few more rows just in case if this is what you really wanted.

I used T-SQL.

```
declare @orig table(
id          int,
quantity    int,
rundate     date
)


insert into @orig
values (1,9,'20220324'),(2072,33,'20220324'),(2072,31,'20220326'),(2072,31,'20220327'),
(2,10,'20220301'),(2,20,'20220325'),(2,30,'20220327')


declare @dates table (
runningdate date
)

insert into @dates
select distinct rundate from @orig
order by rundate


declare @result table (
dates               date,
running_quality     int
)


DECLARE @mydate date
DECLARE @sum int

-- CURSOR definition
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT * FROM @dates

OPEN my_cursor

-- Perform the first fetch
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor into @mydate

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

;with cte as (
select * from @orig
where rundate <= @mydate
), cte2 as (
select id, max(rundate) as maxrundate
from cte
group by id
), cte3 as (
select a.*
from cte as a join cte2 as b
on a.id = b.id and a.rundate = b.maxrundate
)
select @sum = sum(quantity)
from cte3

insert into @result
select @mydate, @sum


-- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor into @mydate

END -- cursor

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor

select * from @result
```

Result:

dates   running_quality
2022-03-01  10
2022-03-24  52
2022-03-25  62
2022-03-26  60
2022-03-27  70